# OOP Example - How do I avoid using a helper class

Tags: oop

I have two classes, one for contacts and another for organisations. Each contact belongs to an organisation and an organisation can have many contacts.

I want a function which creates a contact where one of the parameters is the organisation name. If the organisation name already exists then the contact will be assigned to that existing organisation. Otherwise, a new organisation will be created on the spot for the contact.

Since this function creates a contact and can also possibly create an organisation, my first thought was to create a helper class for it since it doesn't seem to belong to either class. I've been led to believe that helper classes are bad practice in OOP so I'm looking for other suggestions. How would you implement this without the use of a helper class?

Comment: What code you written so far.

Comment: Who told you helper classes are bad practice in OOP? If anything the fact functions are not objects is bad OOP to begin with

Comment: So far the code is just those two classes with functions for creating/deleting/updating objects.

Comment: @Starky post the code please. Edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very difficult to define what exactly is good practice in OOP and what isn't without looking at the specific case in detail. The concerns you are stating are valid, here's my answer to those:

**Helper classes are not necessarily "bad practice" in OOP**

There are quite a few situations, where helper classes are the way to go. If those helper classes simplify your design, they are actually favorable.

**An object function may create other objects - this does not mean it has to go into a helper class.**

If your contact creates an organization, that's fine. If an organization creates a contact, that's fine as well. Those two classes are part of your object design and may depend on one another without violating any design rules in OOP. I don't see why your code "should" go into a helper class at all.

Comment: Thanks Hazzit, this was the type of answer I was looking for